# How to omit values in a threshold when plotting

Tags: gnuplot

I am trying to plot data using `gnuplot`. My data is in a matrix, i.e.:

```
-2 1 2
 0 2 -5
 3 0 1
```

For clarity I would like to assign all values in the threshold -2:2 white color, or assign them as missing. Is there an easy way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

That depends on your actual plotting style and how you encode the color.

When plotting `with image` you can simply mark all values inside your range as invalid (as `1/0`), and then they get plotted as white:

```
$data <<EOD
-2 1 2
 0 2 -5
3 0 1
EOD

plot $data matrix u 1:2:($3 >= -2 && $3 <= 2 ? 1/0 : $3) with image notitle
```

[image]